# Writing to a text file from a list of a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

CS student here, extremely confused about how to solve this problem...
The `mailingLabels.txt` is simply a blank text file.

Here is one sample line from `customerData.txt`:

> `Eric,A,Stutler,568 Nuzum Court,East Aurora,NY,14052,US,Eric.A.Stutler@trashymail.com,716-652-4943,male,11/24/1947`

**Instructions:**

From the `main` function call a new function `generateMailingLabels` to process the customer list to generate a
text file containing mailing labels for only female customers living in Iowa (IA).

The general approach you should take is to:

- pass the `customerList` as a parameter to this function
- open the mailing label file (`mailingLabels.txt`)
- the function should loop over all the customer records in the list
- if a record satisfies the criteria listed above (female from Iowa),
  build the mailing label by concatenating select elements from the
  customer record’s field list, and
- write the mailing label to the file (`mailingLabels.txt`)

Each mailing label should be formatted as below with 5 blank lines separating each label:

> ```
> Jane Smith
> 123 Main Street
> Cedar Falls, IA 50613
> ```

**Here is my current code:**

```
def main():
    """ Opens file, reads customer information into a list, closes the file"""

    custFile = open('customerData.txt','r')
    customerList = generateList(custFile)
    mailingList = open('mailingLabels.txt','w')

    # Echo first and last enter from the customerList
    print "customerList[0]:", customerList[0]
    print "customerList[-1]:",customerList[-1]

    custFile.close()

def generateList(custFile):
    """ Reads customer data from file and returns a list of customers"""
    customers = []
    for line in custFile:
        # Strip the new-line character from the end of the line, then split
        # the line on the commas (',') to get a list of customer fields
        custInfoList = line.strip().split(',')
        customers.append(custInfoList)
    return customers

def generateMailingLabels(customerList):
    """Sorts through the customer list and returns only females living in Iowa."""
    mailingList
    for customer in customerList:
        if customer[5] == 'IA' and customer[10] == 'female':
            mailingList.write(customer)
```

I realize this is probably an easy thing to do I'm just having a hard time grasping how to properly code it so that it does what I want it to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: UPDATED CODE:**

```
def main():
    """ Opens file, reads customer information into a list, closes the file"""

    with (open('customerData.txt','r') as custFile,
          open('mailingLabels.txt','w') as mailingList):

        customerList = generateList(custFile)
        generateMailingLabels(customerList, mailingList)

        # Echo first and last enter from the customerList
        print "customerList[0]:", customerList[0]
        print "customerList[-1]:",customerList[-1]

def generateList(custFile):
    """ Reads customer data from file and returns a list of customers"""
    customers = []
    for line in custFile:
        # Strip the new-line character from the end of the line, then split
        # the line on the commas (',') to get a list of customer fields
        custInfoList = line.strip().split(',')
        customers.append(custInfoList)
    return customers

def generateMailingLabels(customerList,mailingList):
    """Sorts through the customer list and returns only females living in Iowa."""
    open('mailingLabels.txt','w')

    for customer in customerList:
        if customer[5] == 'IA' and customer[10] == 'female':
            mailingList.write(customer)

    mailingList.close()

main()
```

Comment: You should probably call `generateMailingLabels` from `main`. And move the `mailingList = open(...)` statement into `generateMailingLabels`.

Answer (score 0):

You define `mailingList` in the `main()` function, but `generateMailingLabels` doesn't get it. (for one, you don't seem to be calling it)

If you add it in so your main looks more like:

```
def main():
""" Opens file, reads customer information into a list, closes the file"""

    custFile = open('customerData.txt','r')
    customerList = generateList(custFile)
    mailingList = open('mailingLabels.txt','w')

    # Echo first and last enter from the customerList
    print "customerList[0]:", customerList[0]
    print "customerList[-1]:",customerList[-1]

    custFile.close()
    generateMailingLabels(customerList, mailingList)
```

And notice the extra parameter on generateMailingLabels - you have to pass the reference to the function too! The footprint of `generateMailingLabels` now becomes `def generateMailingLabels(customerList, mailingList)` and you can remove that random `mailingList` floating in the first line of it.

EDIT: Also remember to close the mailingList somewhere. Due to that, it's better to learn to just use the `with` statement- it automatically cleans up anything that can work like a file (usually just use it with files)

```
with (open('customerData.txt', 'r') as custFile,
      open('mailingLabels.txt','w') as mailingList):
    customerList = generateList(custFile)
    generateMailingLabels(customerList, mailingList)
```

And then it closes automatically. Otherwise works like any other block structure.

Comment: @touchmybody yeah, figured we should teach the student about with statements since they're magic. I've been tempted to define the necessary functions on my classes to let me use with statements for them too, but I have too few things that are transient.

Comment: I have fixed the things you guys told me about however I am getting a syntax error in the very first 'as' right after i begin the with statement.

Also since there was no mention of the for loop in def generateMailingLabels(customerList,mailingList) that it is correct and should function as intended?

I have updated my code in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Before we get started, I'd like to point out that with Python, you can let the interpreter handle the opening and closing of file streams:

```
with open('customerData.txt','r') as custFile:
    ## do some stuff here that requires the file to be open
    doSomeStuff()

## once outside the loop, Python closes the file for you
doSomeMoreStuff()
```

The nice thing about `with open(path, mode) as foo` is there's no way you'll forget to close your file.

---

As for your program, there's an error in `def generateMailingLabels(customerList):`

The first mistake is that you're not even calling it from your `main()` function.  How is the function going to run if you don't call it?

The next thing I see is here:

```
mailingList
for customer in customerList:
    if customer[5] == 'IA' and customer[10] == 'female':
        mailingList.write(customer)
```

In python, you can't declare unassigned variables.  The line that says `mailingList` does nothing but throw an error.  Also, you're calling `mailingList.write()` even though it's not instantiated.  You need to open the file *inside that function*, or pass in the opened `mailingList` into it.  I'd recommend opening it inside that function instead of passing it in, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments in your methods should be meaningful and describe what the method is doing. For example, the comment on your `generateMailingList` method has nothing to do with what the method is actually doing.

Further, as you are using Python, you should follow the [style guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when writing your code.

You can further simplify your code - at the same time making it a bit more flexible, by passing in the filenames to the methods instead of the file handlers. Keep in mind that a function should do only one thing - if a function is doing two/three different it makes it difficult to debug and isolate problems; not to mention write good tests.

So let us start with the three things your program needs to do:

1. Read the source file
2. Filter out the records matching a criteria
3. Write the results

Let us start writing these functions individually:

```
def read_records(filename, separator=','):
    "This method reads the source CSV file and returns a list of records"
    results = []
    with open(filename) as f:
       for line in f:
          if line.strip():  # skips blank lines
              results.append(line.split(','))

    return results

def filter_records(records):
    gender = 'female'
    state = 'IA'
    results = []
    for record in records:
       if record[5] == state and record[10] == gender:
           results.append(record)
    return results

def write_results(filename, records):
    "Writes out filtered records, with 5 spaces between each entry"
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
       for record in records:
           name = '{} {} {}'.format(record[0], record[1], record[2])
           address = '{}\n{}, {} {}'.format(record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6])
           f.write('{}\n{}\n\n\n\n\n'.format(name, address))
```

Next, we need to call them in the correct order:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = read_records('customerData.txt')
    filtered_records = filter_records(records)
    write_results('mailingLabels.txt', filtered_records)
    print('Done')
```

---

*There are some places in the code that you can optimize, depending on what you have been taught in class.*